# Xamarin.UI test Exception

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I try to Execute some simple UI tests on Xamarin Android.

*AppInitializer:*

```
public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
{
    if (platform == Platform.Android)
    {
        return ConfigureApp
            .Android
            .ApkFile(@"D:\DEMO UI\DemoApp\DemoApp\DemoApp.Android\bin\Release\com.companyname.DemoApp.apk")
            .StartApp();
    }
    return ConfigureApp
        .iOS
        .StartApp();
}
```

*Tests*

```
IApp app;
Platform platform;

public Tests(Platform platform)
{
    this.platform = platform;
}
[SetUp]
public void BeforeEachTest()
{
    app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
}
[Test]
public void ButtonClick()
{
    app.Tap("Mybutt");
    var labelresult = app.Query("Mylabel").First(result => result.Text == "New text");
    Assert.IsTrue(labelresult != null, "correct UI result");
}
```

But when I click Run selected text then got a message :

> Message: SetUp : System.Exception : Failed to execute: C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   emulator-5554 install -g
>   "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-35C99D3B2B84FFBF5EA16C49D8C264A148107FF6\final-BD39EFD80A0C98583FA77A85C7E24A8C14BDF412.apk"
>   - exit code: 1 Failed to install C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-35C99D3B2B84FFBF5EA16C49D8C264A148107FF6\final-BD39EFD80A0C98583FA77A85C7E24A8C14BDF412.apk:
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native
>   libraries, res=-113]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i was find the solution:

1) First one - You must use the `Release` not `Debug`.

2) Go to the Properties of you Project in Solution - alt+Enter(in my case it was DemoApp.Android).

2.1) take off the `Use Shared runtime`

2.2) in `Linker Properties` set `Sdk assembly only`

2.3) Advanced -> Supported architectures : select x86_x64; x86; armeabi-v7a;

3) Then rebuild solution and you *.apk file.

4) start android emulator

5) start you  UI test

Hope this help someone else.